# php code run successfully but no any database created in mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new in PHP and mongoDB i just want to create a database and a collection into mongoDB database but the problem is my whole code runs successfully without error but no any DB created in mongoDB

Here is my Code

```
<?php
   $m=new MongoClient();
   $db=$m->ashu;
   $renu_collection=$db->renu;
   $doc=array(
    "name"=>"ashutosh",
     "reg"=>123
        );
   echo "Connection established"
        ?>
```